# Before paper submission, the EIC advised that the paper topic and length is not appropriate. The paper actually falls into the scope of the journal

Tags: paper-submission

I contacted the EIC before submission to inquire if they would accept a paper of 15 pages and he advised that the paper topic and length is not appropriate. The paper actually falls into the scope of the journal and sent him another email message explaining that but did not reply. Shall I submit.

Comment: I agree with the comment below.  It's probably a nice way of saying: your paper's quality is poor, and doesn't belong in this journal.

Comment: The first rule of successful publishing: Do not argue with the EiC.

Comment: You (and the answers below) say nothing on the length - is the paper within the length limits of the journal? Are there other similar-length papers in the last year or so of issues?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, which is meaningful.

Answer (score 12):

> the [editor in chief] advised that *the paper topic and length is not appropriate* (emphasis added)

But, you contest,

> The paper actually falls into the scope of the journal

I believe you are wrong: The editor in chief is in a better position to judge whether your paper is in scope. You should consider their decision final.

> [I] sent him another email message explaining that [his decision was wrong] but did [he] not reply.

The editor in chief has made their position clear, I am not surprised they did not respond.

> Shall I submit.

No, **you shouldn't submit**, you've been advised that **your paper is not in scope**.

Answer (score 3):

You get told that the paper topic and length is not appropriate, so have you made suitable changes to the paper?

If you have then submit.

If you have not then don't submit. If you ignore that and submit anyway, then expect it to be rejected.